# Recalculate field using value from another field in document & calculation

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Doing this in node.js with mongodb-native package.

Lets say documents have this structure:

```
{
  name: "Document A", // just a string field
  var1: 10, // some variable, it is increaded if user do a cetrain action
  date_created: '2014-01-07' // stored as ISO date, here I simplified it,
}
```

For each document in collection I must create-if-not-exist or update **varComp** variable, and its value should be calculated using values from current document. The calculation formula is something like this (pseudocode):

```
varComp = (5 + var1) / (Date.now() - date_created)^2.5
```

Updating, as far as I know, in this case must be performed with aggregation framework (due to division), but how do I calculate the power 2.5 of 2 dates difference, which must be expressed in hours before raising? I cannot calculate it on insert/update of **var1** only, because regardless every document must be recalculated each, lets say, 5 hours by calling an *Recalculate* routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.It is not possible to update data in database using aggregation framework. But using aggregation framework you could do some calculations on fly. Unfortunately pow operation is not implemented in Aggregation Framework. You should use MapReduce instead.

2.Alternatively you could have some separate process that would do calculations by schedule(every 5 hours) and write results in database.
Implementation for MongoDb shell:

```
var myCursor =  db.yourCollection.find({ });

myCursor.forEach(function(d){ 

  var varComp = (5 + d.var1) / Math.pow(Date.now() - d.date_created, 2.5);

  db.yourCollection.update({_id:d._id},{$set:{ varComp: varComp }});

});
```

Comment: The second varinat is what I am trying to do. Every 5 hours I must update varComp for every record. The question is how to calculate this variable and update it with recalculated value.

Comment: Neither aggregate framework nor MapReduce are helpful in this case. You should scan collection, do computations and write it back. So db.yourCollection.find for collection + db.yourCollection.update for each document.

Comment: All right, how about then calculate date difference and power of a number in an update query? This is the major issue here.